# State changed in componentWillReceiveProps is not showing up in the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined a state in my constructor and it's like this

```
      this.state={
            datainaccordion:'',

        };
```

Now in my componentWillReceiveProps , I have changed the state everytime we receive new Props and it is like this,

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log('something',nextProps);
        if (nextProps.data) {
        this.setState({ datainaccordion: nextProps.data });
       }
       console.log('this.state.datainaccordion ',this.state.datainaccordion);
    }
```

I can see the console and it is working fine every time a new data comes but when I console log the same state inside render I don't see this console. What can be the reason for this and why is it happening?
Another thing is that I have put another console.log('rendering') inside my render and even this doesn't show up.
How do i make it render everytime I get new data?
I am adding the render part too here .

```
render(){
         console.log('rendering');  // this is not being printed  
        console.log('rung',this.state.datainaccordion);
     // some logic to extract an array out of the data in this .state.datainaccordion and we call it arraytoloop



        return (
            <div>
                     <SomeComponentXYz

                       data={arraytoloop}

                       />
              </div>


       );    }

 }
```

Comment: can you add code for render()?

Comment: are you sure shouldComponentUpdate hook is not returning false?

Comment: render is ok. Maybe error is in shouldComponentUpdate as said above or you extend from PureComponent

Comment: Hey I have not used ShouldComponentUpadte anywhere.

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Yes , I extend from PureComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @satyajeet jha said

This Component is extended from PureComponent.
But PureComponent has implemented **shouldComponentUpdate**.

> React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() only shallowly compares
>   the objects. 
>   ...
>   Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have
>   simple props and state

and your field *datainaccordion* is object as I suppose. So shouldComponentUpdate in PureComponent will return false and stop updating because it doesnt check difference between old and new object

Comment: Hey kiril does it mean that PureComponent has shouldUpdate  return set to false as Default .I read that shouldUpdate has default return as true.

Comment: @satyajeetjha there is no "default". There is function checkShouldComponentUpdate([source file to watch](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js)) which is used as shouldComponentUpdate in PureComponent